# PHP - JPEG Image to RGB value Array

Tags: php, arrays, jpeg

I am wanting to get an array of RGB values from an image. E.g. (2 X 2 pix example.)

```
[[[R, G, B], [R, G, B]], [[R, G, B], [R, G, B]]]
```

The code I have now:

```
<?php
// open an image
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg'); // imagecreatefromjpeg/png/
// get image dimension, define colour array
$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);
$colors = [];
for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++)
{
    for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++)
    {
        $rgb = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
        $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
    } 
}
print_r($colors);
?>
```

The above is not working.
My image is now just a 2 X 2 pix jpeg which should output:

```
    [[[0, 255, 0], [255, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 255], [255, 255, 255]]]
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your not adding `$r $g $b` to your `$colors` array ... I would start there. `$colors[] = array($r,$g,$b);`

Comment: Did you just forget to push the $r, $g, and $b into your $colors array?  I'm not seeing where you do that in the code above.

Comment: True. Thanks, have added. Just getting "Array ()" output now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, nailed it. Thanks to all.

```
<?php
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg'); // imagecreatefromjpeg/png/

$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);
$colors = array();

for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
$y_array = array() ;

for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
    $rgb = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
    $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
    $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
    $b = $rgb & 0xFF;

    $x_array = array($r, $g, $b) ;
    $y_array[] = $x_array ; 
} 
$colors[] = $y_array ;
}

print_r($colors);
?>
```

Comments correct, added $r, $g, $b. Restructured @jari answer and now getting a good output.

Cheers!

Comment: Hey, do you know how to convert this array back into an image?

Answer (score 1):

```
function getArrayOfPixelsFromFile($source) {
 $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source); // imagecreatefromjpeg/png/

 $width = imagesx($image);
 $height = imagesy($image);
 $colors = array();

 for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
    $y_array = array();
    for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
        //Seleciona a cor localizada em ($x, $y)
        $rgb = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
        //echo $rgb." = ".decbin($rgb),"<br>";
        //Seleciona os primeiros dois bytes que representam vermelho
        $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        //Seleciona os dois bytes do meio que representam o verde
        $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        //Seleciona os dois últimos bytes que representam o azul
        $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
        $x_array = array($r, $g, $b);
        $y_array[] = $x_array;
    }
    $colors[] = $y_array;
  }
  return $colors;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code by creating subarrays and adding elements to it as it should be.

```
for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++)
{
    $height_arr = array() ;

    for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++)
    {
        $rgb = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
        $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $b = $rgb & 0xFF;

        $width_arr = array($r, $g, $b) ;
        $height_array[] = $width_arr ; 
    } 

    $colors[] = $height_arr ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
[...]
$colors = [];
for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
    for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
        $rgb = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
        $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
        $colors[$y][$x] = array($r,$g,$b);  // or, $colors[$x][$y] = array($r,$g,$b);
    } 
}
print_r($colors);
```